# JQuery Mobile + Google Analytics in hybrid app

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I would like to develop a hybrid app with jquery mobile. Does anybody integrate Google analytics in such a project? Does it work?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Hi i had worked on this type of applications. you can use google analytics.By editing google analytics js([googel analytics js](http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js)). You can find clear details [here](http://www.blastam.com/blog/index.php/2013/07/ga-universal-analytics-phonegap-mobile-apps/).It is working perfect for me.

Comment: @rookee does it worked for u? if not i will gave u complete code